# When I run this project these errors show up, how to solve them?

Tags: android

Why are these errors showing up?

```
done/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v28/values-v28.xml 

Error: (7, 41) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius'). 

Error: (7, 41) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius'). 

Error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: Add your gradle with `buildToolsVersion`.

Comment: Please provide details of what you are trying to do and the code which leads to this error

Comment: last time code work properly but now it give error

Comment: update your buildTools

Comment: Have you updated your build tools and platforms recently? This seems related to the release of the Android P developer preview last night.

Comment: @user3385125 A solution has been found in this question, it's probably the same issue as what you're having:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49172361/469080

Answer (score 0):

these is related to build version issue 27.0.3. In app  gradle decrease build tool version first and delete .gradle ,.idea and gradle folder and rebuild project problem is solve .