# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius')

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, build-error

Can anybody help why I am getting an error in the following?

> Error:(7, 41) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius').

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//Add these lines
def Base_URL = '"' + WEBServiceBaseURL + '"' ?: '"Define BASE URL"';
def SMS_Base_URL = '"' + WEBServiceBaseSMSURL + '"' ?: '"Define SMS BASE URL"';

android.buildTypes.each { type ->
    type.buildConfigField 'String', 'Base_URL', WEBServiceBaseURL
    type.buildConfigField 'String', 'SMS_Base_URL', WEBServiceBaseSMSURL
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bla.bla"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled  true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile files('libs/jxl-2.6.jar')
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I note an identical error from half an hour ago. Have you updated any library versions recently? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170669/i-am-run-project-these-issue-show-how-to-solve-it

Comment: No I haven't updated anything!

Comment: Try changing your `buildToolsVersion` to 26.0.2

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: @PavanPyati check docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#dialogCornerRadius

Comment: @NileshRathod Well TIL. Never realised it was a P-specific thing. Thanks

Comment: @NileshRathod where do I need to use this?

Comment: @NileshRathod, Michael could help me,like to use this?

Comment: @PavanPyati Well, it looks like a pretty new thing, the only Google results for `attr/dialogCornerRadius` currently are this question and the one I linked above. Something may have changed in Android Studio, I'm not sure what yet.

Comment: If you do `ctrl + shift + F` and search for `dialogCornerRadius`, do you get any results?

Comment: @MichaelDodd, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I note that the Android P developer preview was released last night. Is it possible that your Android Studio has downloaded the P platform and Build Tools 28.0.0-rc1? Can you check this in your SDK settings?

Comment: @MichaelDodd Nothing is updated so far, my latest update is 26.0.0

Comment: For those coming from Ionic/Cordova like me, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49200782/3054411).

Comment: I already answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517187/2145504

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I fixed this issue by selecting

> API 27+: Android API 27, P preview (Preview)

in the project structure settings. Following image shows my setting. The 13 errors that were coming while building the app, have disappeared.

[image: My Gradle settings]

Comment: @Jon, Its not giving any error. Thanks for the answer but I'm unable to run in my Device, as its giving 
minSdk(API 27, P preview)! = deviceSdk(API 24)

Any idea what can be done?

Comment: @PavanPyati what do you have in your build.gradle file for these values?

compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

Comment: @Jon yes, same like what you mentioned.

Comment: Build is successful but i could not able to install this apk in device.
am facing the issue while installing the apk is: There was a problem parsing the package.

Comment: Same here - can't install on device - Failure 
[INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK:... Requires development platform P but this is a release platform]

Comment: May I know how to solve this error in ionic3 project, please?

Comment: Looks like you can set `compileSdkVersion 'android-P'` in your build.gradle file as well, but how you would figure that out without using the IDE I don't know.

Comment: I was struggling with `style attribute 'android:attr/dialogCornerRadius' not found.` and many more isues regarding resource not found. I solved by updating compile sdk version to 29 (in my case variables.gradle had `compileSdkVersion = 29`) as shown in screenshot. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 16):

set your **compileSdkVersion 28**
let android studio download platform files

Answer (score 5):

if in your app level gradle if you have used compileSdkVersion = 27 then it will not work. 
You have to use version 28.

`compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'`

Answer (score 3):

Change the line `compile 'com.android.support:design:+'` to `compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'`

The gradle dependencies when the project is built is pulling down the latest versions since the `+` was telling it "get the latest version."  the `26.+` will tell the build process to only update the latest version of v26.

Or to be even more specific and safe, change the line to a specific version, avoiding the `+` altogether. i.e. `compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'`

Comment: @PepaHruška added clarification on how to use specific version number

Answer (score 3):

Change the following depedencies in your gradle:

---

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

---

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

to:

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

---

Please note that you can specify any version, but make sure they both have the same version.

This will make sure that `values-28.xml` file is not created.

Comment: You should accumulate 50 reputations firstly.

Answer (score 0):

After Everybody's help, I could resolve this issue & run app in lower version.

My updated build.gradle is like below.

Special thanks to all Genius out there!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android.buildTypes.each { type ->
    type.buildConfigField 'String', 'Base_URL', WEBServiceBaseURL
    type.buildConfigField 'String', 'SMS_Base_URL', WEBServiceBaseSMSURL
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dummy.dummy"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled  true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile files('libs/jxl-2.6.jar')
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: i have done the change. i used compileSdkVersion as android-P and buildToolVersion as 26 . i get build successful but not installing in device.

Comment: if i use compileSdkVersion  as 27 then its not working.

Answer (score 0):

forget about dynamic dependencies and replace them with fixed specific versions :

**WRONG :**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile files('libs/jxl-2.6.jar')
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
}
```

**CORRECT :**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile files('libs/jxl-2.6.jar')
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error after unsuccessful migration to AndroidX.
I reverted all changes which Android Studio made, cleaned project, invalidated cache/restart, and many other things but with no luck.
Finally I found that Android Studio added two lines to gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

After remove those lines everything back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all but it did not work. Finally, it worked after I changed target to 28 in platforms/android/project.properties.

change

```
target=android-26
```

to

```
target=android-28
```

Thanks