# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dial ogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius')

Tags: android, cordova

It happened to me from a day to another that this error appeared after the cordova build command. It seemes an error caused by the recent release of SDK 27 P preview. here the full error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
>    What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>
> Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   C:\Users...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7:41-73: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialog
>   CornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius').
>
> Failed to generate resource table for split ''
>   C:\Users...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dial
>   ogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius').
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49172361/9469206) a way to solve the problem but it doesn't work 100% because the build ends without errors but I'm not able to install the apk on my phone because a device with apiSDK 27 is required. 
The only way to work it seems to be setting the Compile SDK Version to 27+ P preview otherwise that error is shown.

Does someone know a workaround or a way to fix it (either or directly on cordova or editing the manifest.xml is fine anyway)?

Comment: am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should check your added plugin carefully to find if there are some plugins using design lib like: `compile 'com.android.support:design:+'`. Take care of some plugins may use a separate gradle file. If your cordova android version is 6+, you can change the design dependency to `com.android.support:design:26.+`.

I'm facing the same issue, and I found a plugin written by myself has the problem said above. After fix that, it works well. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I've checked every single compile in every installed plugin but I don't have 'com.android.support:design'.  Instead I've found 'com.android.support:support-v4:+ ' and I tried to change it in 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+' but nothing changed and I still get the same error.

I even tried to set the config.xml with
<platform name="android">
        <framework src="com.android.support:design:26.+"/>
    </platform>

but still nothing

Comment: I've solved the problem. I've just found a plugin who was using this
<framework src="com.android.support:customtabs:+" />

I've changed to 
<framework src="com.android.support:customtabs:26.+" />
and that solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've added the following plugin to the config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" source="npm" spec="1.2.0"/>
```

it resolved problem.