# Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found

Tags: android, attr

So I installed android studio 3.0.1 and as soon as it opened the gradle built and showed the following errors. I tried adding dependencies such as design and support but in vain. Could someone help me?

[image]

It shows that some attributes such as `dialogCornerRadius` and `fontVariation` Settings not found.

Comment: I had `compileSdkVersion 27` and `compileSdkVersion 28`, changing `compileSdkVersion` to `28`, solved the problem.

Answer (score 202):

This error occurs because of mismatched `compileSdkVersion` and
library version.

for example:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

and also avoid to use + sign with library as in the following:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

use exact library version like this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Using + sign with the library makes it difficult for the building process to gather the exact version that is required, making system unstable, hence should be discouraged.

Comment: I had to update my compileSdkVersion major version number to be the same as com.android.support:support-annotations, com.android.support:appcompat-v7, com.android.support:support-v4, com.android.support:design

Comment: This was the solution in my case

Answer (score 89):

If you are migrated for AndroidX and getting this error, you need to set the compile SDK to Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher

Comment: any way to have androidX with sdkcompiled 27?

Comment: @Phil Before you migrate, bring your app up to date. We recommend updating your project to use the final version of the support library: version 28.0.0. This is because AndroidX artifacts with version 1.0.0 are binary equivalent to the Support Library 28.0.0 artifacts.[Source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#prerequisites). So there is no options for sdk 27 with androidX

Answer (score 28):

I had the exact same issue. The following thread helped me solve it. Just set your Compile SDK version to Android P.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49172361/1542720

> I fixed this issue by selecting:
>
> > API 27+: Android API 27, P preview (Preview)
>
> in the project structure settings. the following image shows my
>   settings. The 13 errors that were coming while building the app, have
>   disappeared.
>
> [image: Gradle settings]

Comment: *notice*, you don't have to TARGET it to 28, you can just set `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` to 28 and leave your `targetSdkVersion` at a lower version

Answer (score 18):

Had the same issue while working on an application with several modules, check to make sure as you increase the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 28+ values in a module you also do for the others.

A module was running on `compileSdkVersion 29` and `targetSdkVersion 29` while a second module of the application was running on `compileSdkVersion 27` and `targetSdkVersion 27`.

Changing the second module to also compile for and target SDK version 29 resolved my issue. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Comment: Yup. LVL licensing needed to be bumped, thanks for this.

Answer (score 17):

Check your dependencies for uses of `+` in the versions. Some dependency could be using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+`. This leads to problems when a new version gets released and could break features.

The solution for this would be to either use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{compileSdkVersion}.+` or don't use `+` at all and use the full version  (ex. `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0`).

If you cannot see a line in your build.gradle files for this, run in android studio terminal to give an overview of what each dependency uses

`gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath` (include androidtest dependencies)

OR

`gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugCompileClasspath` (regular dependencies for debug)

which results in something that looks close to this

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

debugCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: debug
...
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:26.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:26.1.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

If you have no control over changing the version, Try forcing it to use a specific version.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
        force "com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0"
    }
}
```

The force dependency may need to be different depending on what is being set to 28.0.0

Comment: `bash: gradlew: command not found` Any suggestions where to find it?

Comment: Ah, found it myself. Funny that on Linux you often can't execute a command in the current directory without prefacing it by `./`, so: `./gradlew` etc.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe it's too late but i found a solution:

You have to edit in the `build.gradle` either the `compileSdkVersion` --> to lastest (now it is 28). Like that:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

or you can change the version of implementation:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    api 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 9):

try to change the compileSdkVersion to: `compileSdkVersion 28`

Comment: But I want it to be 26.

Comment: Yes I also want to be in 26. any solution @TaslimOseni

Comment: @VigneswaranA, I eventually had to stick to 28 and thus update all my other dependencies. I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 8):

**This Is Because compileSdkVersion , buildToolsVersion and Dependecies implementations are not match 
You Have to done like this i have 28 library then**

```
compileSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion   28
buildToolsVersion  28.0.3
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

If we You Use Any where less than 28 this error should occured so please try match library in all.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I was getting this error in AndroidStudio 4.1.1 while updating compileSdkVersion to 29.

If you are having dependent project in build.gradle, All you need to do is Update same compileSdkVersion in dependent project's build.gradle as well.

Steps:

1. Click on your app folder in Project view of AndroidStudio.
2. Select Open Module Settings.
3. In Project Structure >> Check how many modules are there?
4. If there are more than one modules, you will have to update compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion & Project dependency as well.

That worked for me :)

Comment: That's it, Realy thank you. I got stuck on it and you save my days.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue while adding a mapbox navigation API and resolved this issue by going to: file>project Structure and then setting the compile sdk version and build tool version to the latest. 
And here is the screenshot: 
[image: settings Screenshot]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Found a neat plugin to solve this:
cordova-android-support-gradle-release

cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=27.+ --save

Answer (score 2):

in my case, I try tried `File`>`Invalidate Cache/Restart` and that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies must be applied as shown below to solve this issue :

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
}
```

Please do not use the version of  :

> v7:28.0.0-alpha1

Comment: If you use compile SDK 28 and build tools 28.0.1 you can.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem but I successfully solved the problem by changing the version of compileSdkVersion to the latest which is 29 and change the version of targetSdkVersion to the latest which is 29.

Go to the gradile.build file and change the compilesdkversion and targetsdkversion.

Answer (score 1):

change useAndroidX and enableJetifier to false in the file gradle.properties  and remove androidx in Dependecies in my case

Answer (score 1):

compileSdkVersion 28, changing compileSdkVersion to 28, solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error ocurred while i was using 
the

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:+'
```

libraries together with googles

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material-components:+'
```

library. If this is the case in your project, i highly recommend to fully remove the google material components library from your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
 buildscript {

    project.ext {
        supportLibVersion = '27.1.1'
        compileVersion = 28
        minSupportedVersion = 22
    }
}
```

and set dependencies:

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$project.supportLibVersion"
```

Comment: I am getting build error `Gradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'supportLibVersion' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project. (11 s 585 ms)` when I followed your solution. how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your min compileSdkVersion is 29

Second, You need to match the compileSdkVersion and the compatible buildToolsVersion.
You can refer the following answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71663728/9420335

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by adding this to build.gradle (:app)
in the android section

compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility 1.8
targetCompatibility 1.8
}