# Unable to find optional library: android.test.runner

Tags: android, testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation

I am attempting to follow android developer documentation's `Set up project for AndroidX Test` tutorial ([found here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project)) but am getting the error `unable to find optional library: android.test.runner`.

Here is my Gradle file:

```
...

android {

    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    ...

    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'

}

...

dependencies {
    ...

    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
}
```

As you can see, I have `android.test.runner` in my dependencies, but when I add the line `useLibrary 'android.test.runner'` in my android block, I get the error that it can't find that library...

Is there something off with my Gradle file? I'm following the instructions that were outlined on the tutorial, so I don't know what I could possibly be missing...

Comment: What API level version are you using? I run into the same problem but now found a statement in the tutorial that caused the problem on my side: "The lists in this section show how the platform organizes JUnit-based classes in Android 9 (API level 28) and higher."

Answer (score 1):

I just **not added** these useless lines and it is still working even if that is in the [**official**](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project) guideline.

But if you are migrating the old version to androidx, remember you have to change the compiling version to 28 otherwise will get some [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280632/error9-5-error-resource-androidattr-dialogcornerradius-not-found).