# How to fix linking error on Android project

Tags: android

My compiler just showed this error. I have no idea what happened.

I'm testing a project which runs with firebase. On its request, I just went to project structure to change my minsdk to 26, but after I changed it, it provides these errors.

Since this is my first Android project, I have no idea what has happened.

Can somebody give me a hand and help me get through it?

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1894: error: resource drawable/edit_text_background_dark_round (aka com.example.myapplication:drawable/edit_text_background_dark_round) not found.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1897: error: resource drawable/ic_down_arrow (aka com.example.myapplication:drawable/ic_down_arrow) not found.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v21\values-v21.xml:282: error: resource drawable/edit_text_background_dark_round (aka com.example.myapplication:drawable/edit_text_background_dark_round) not found.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v21\values-v21.xml:285: error: resource drawable/ic_down_arrow (aka com.example.myapplication:drawable/ic_down_arrow) not found.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2786: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2787: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280632/error9-5-error-resource-androidattr-dialogcornerradius-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> check XML files cause "android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found"
>   means that   'dialogCornerRadius' is not defined , you can replace it
>   with value like "2dp" or initialise it in ' dimens.xml'   check this
>   link to create 'dimen' file

[How to use dimens.xml in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128178/how-to-use-dimens-xml-in-android)