# AAPT style attribute not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using android studio version 4.1.3 and gradle version 6.8.3 . My target sdk version for the project is API 26.

After clicking on `sync the project`, the result seems have no problem but after clicking on `run app`, I have an error which says,

```
gradle-6.8.3\caches\transforms-3\71de35e86c45a332199eb23f9129d32f\transformed\material-1.4.0\res\values\values.xml:1316:-1327:11:  AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/dialogCornerRadius' not found
```

I don't know what should I do?

Just tell me if you need more details for better diagnosis.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question seems duplicate to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280632/error9-5-error-resource-androidattr-dialogcornerradius-not-found

Comment: Hi, i have corrected the mistakes but still have the error infront of myself. Can you help me?

Comment: Please add your app level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I use android studio version 4.1.3 and gradle version 6.8.3 . My target sdk version is api 26

Comment: Please tell me if any more info is needed