# gradle not coordinated with the project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using android studio version 4.1.3 and gradle version 6.8.3 . My target sdk version for the project is API 26.

After clicking on `sync the project`, the result seems have no problem but after clicking on `run app`, I have some errors. One of them says,

```
gradle-6.8.3\caches\transforms-3\71de35e86c45a332199eb23f9129d32f\transformed\material-1.4.0\res\values\values.xml:1316:-1327:11:  AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/dialogCornerRadius' not found
```

I have seen the [Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280632/error9-5-error-resource-androidattr-dialogcornerradius-not-found)

But again the problem is not solved

I don't know what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the cache and restart?

Comment: Do you think it will gonna work?