# Unable to Distribute apk while upgraded CompileSdkVersion to 'Android-P' and reverting to old version gives Errors

Tags: android, sdk, apk, release, android-9.0-pie

I am stuck with an Issue with New Android SDK for 'Android P'.

Before release of new SDK my project was working fine and I was able to build and release fine. Immediately after it's release, I started getting Build Error as below.

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius')
```

After having research I was able to find the solution given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171300/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-dialogcornerradius-with-valu)

I applied the solution and added `compileSdkVersion 'android-P`' in `gradle` and project started building up without errors. I also was able to run the app on my device fine after building and loading from Android Studio.

However when I build/ generate the `apk` for distribution this `apk` while installing on the device gives error `App not Installed`. For which I came to know that since this `Android P` SDK is a Preview development platform so we cannot distribute.
So I am stuck in this situation as I cannot revert back to the old version where I get build errors and while working with `Android P SDK` I am unable to distribute.

Any suggestions or help/ guidance on the matter will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Saleem

Comment: Follow the instructions in the other answers to [the question that you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171300/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-dialogcornerradius-with-valu). My guess is that you have a `+` sign for the version of one of your `dependencies`, and that is trying to use Android P-level stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CommonsWare I don't have + sign with any of my dependencies. Also I have tried following the answer to your given link which are not helpful in my case.